# Nil value when referring to IBOutlets - swift, Cocoa

Tags: swift, cocoa

I am having an issue where my NSTextField IBOutlets are showing up as nil, even though they are connected to the storyboard. In the simplified example below, I have a button that, when pressed, should list the string value of the 3 text labels.

Here is the code for the button:

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSObject{

    @IBAction func pushButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        let oneText = Texts()
        oneText.listTextFields()
    }

}
```

Here is the code for the NSTextField list:

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

class Texts: NSObject{

    @IBOutlet weak var l1: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var l2: NSTextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var l3: NSTextField!

    var textArray = [NSTextField]()

    func listTextFields (){
      self.textArray = [self.l1,self.l2,self.l3]

        for var i = 0; i < textArray.count; i++ {
            let text = textArray[i]
            print(text.stringValue)
        }
    }
}
```

I have verified that the IBOutlets are all connected, but I get a "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" message when I run the program and press the button. Looking at the debugger, it appears that the tree NSTextfields are "nil."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not loading `Texts` from your storyboard, so it knows nothing about your outlets. `Texts()` creates a new instance of the object, which you then call the method on.

You presumably have an existing `Texts` object somewhere in interface builder, `ViewController` should have an outlet to that.